# Pass 3 values per run on for loop

Tags: php, algorithm, loops

I still cannot think of the right algorithm, I have one session variable where information is stored how to create form and it looks like this: $_SESSION['formsarray']=> ['form1'] form2... etc. and the form1 has array which stores information about input type, input name and required attribut so it's basically 2 dimensional array. All these 3 attributes need to be sorted out (there are more of these attributes in form1 like inputtype1, inputname1, req1 and then inputtype2, inputname2, req2, etc. the number defines the input element which is being created) in a foreach loop and passed to a function, So that's what I thought so far:

```
 foreach($_SESSION['formsarray'] as $form){
    echo "form number".$i."<br>";
    foreach($form as $no=>$value){
        echo "/// key: ".$no."//// value: ".$value."<br>";
        if(strpos($no, 'inputtype') !== false){
            $typepos[] = $value;
        }
        if(strpos($no, 'inputname') !== false) {
            $namepos[] = $value;
        }
        if(strpos($no, 'req') !== false) {
            $reqpost[] = $value;
        }

    $formatted['form'.$i] = sorting($typepos['type'.$j], $namepos['name'.$j]);
        $j++;
    }
    $j = 0;
    echo"<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

but it's wrong, I was thinking to replace the second foreach loop with for loop and with knowledge that we have 3 attributes which belong to each other, run for loop with division by 3 so that it sorts and passes 3 values at the same time to a function, resets iterator and then runs again, does anyone has a better solution?